# rails bundle install via proxy on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, proxy, installation, rubygems, bundle

I'm trying to run bundle install from behind a proxy in windows, it's not working. Is there a setting somewhere i can change to make it happen?

I know the proxy is the issue because it worked before and that's the only thing that could have messed things up

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's what has worked for me:

Go to the system properties (right click "My Computer" > Properties).
In the advanced tab, look for the "Environment variables button".
Add a variable called http_proxy with the value http://username:password@proxyserver:port

Restart your console and you should be good to go.

A few caveats:

- by experience, drop the domain in your username (if you have one)
- some passwords will break this (e.g. passwords which contain an @ sign)

Comment: Yay, thanks! Telling me to restart the console is how you ended my frustration :(

Comment: You can also use Fiddler (https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) with "Rules | Automatically Authenticate" enabled and it will handle NTLM too!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is STILL having trouble with the bundler, try using CNTLM to configure `http://localhost:3128` as your proxy. Then follow the steps in this answer. FINALLY worked for me.